# CompoundButton setButtondrawable is hiding the text behind

Tags: android

I have CustomButton which extends CompundButton . Drawables for this button is setting at runtime for different states. The text which is set in adapter for this button is being hidden for some of the states. I want to view text and drawables both in all states without adding textview in layout.

If any links or sample code really helps a lot.

Thanks in Adavnce.

Comment: In other way the z order can be used in single view as text and drawable are both different properties.

Comment: For any one facing this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624205/is-it-possible-to-modify-z-order-for-textview-and-drawable-in-button  will gives some idea.