# Is it possible to modify z-order for textview and drawable in Button?

Tags: android, button, layout

I created Custom Button which extends Compound Button but the textview is behind the drawable of the button. I want text of Button should come up and drawable should go behind without creating other view in the layout.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Any Link or sample code helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CompoundButton` is an abstract class which is mainly used to create other views from SDK like `Checkbox` or `Switch` and it has it's own limitations and specific behaviour.

There are different ways to implement it much easier and without `CompoundButton` dependency.

1. Create your own `ViewGroup` and use children as layers. There're methods to change `z-order`: `view.bringToFront` and `group.bringChildToFront`. This class rotates three layers every second.

```
static class LayeredButton extends RelativeLayout {

    public LayeredButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Button buttonA = new Button(context);
        Button buttonB = new Button(context);
        Button buttonC = new Button(context);

        buttonA.setText("a");
        buttonB.setText("b");
        buttonC.setText("c");

        addView(buttonC);
        addView(buttonB);
        addView(buttonA);

        rotateChildren();
    }

    void rotateChildren(){
        postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getChildAt(0).bringToFront();
                rotateChildren();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

2. Another option is just to switch visibility of views: `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` also inside `ViewGroup`

3. And last one is draw it "manually" using `Canvas`. This is probably the most flexible way to do it. Also has better performance and gives you opportunity to add custom animation.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawRect(rect);//bottom layer
    canvas.drawText(text);//mid layer
    canvas.drawLine(line);//top layer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  1st option indirectly tells that this can achieve with multiple views. 3rd option which is the one within single view can achieve this . The key is OnDraw order. I checked the TextView which is the base for Button has the order of first drawable then text.